# Flutter/Firestore: startAfter includes the item that its supposed to start after only on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why but this is just an iOS only issue, it works just fine on Android. When the user loads up the chat it reads new incoming messages and looks for any previous messages in case the user hasn't seen them. The problem is the `.startAfter` is including the last message, but only on iOS, on Android it works just fine.

At launch it looks for missing messages, if there are it adds to the list of messages, then it starts to listen to incoming messages. If there isn't any missing messages it just listens to incoming messages. But in both cases the last message is being re-read.

```
  Future<List<Message>> missingMessages({Chat chat}) async {
    Query query = this
        .collection
        .doc(chat.chatID)
        .collection(Constants.messages)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: false)
        .startAfter([chat.messages.last.createdAt]);

    return (await Services().crud.readDocs(
            query: query))
        .docs
        .map(
          (documentSnapshot) => Message.model(
            ds: documentSnapshot,
            id: documentSnapshot.id,
            map: documentSnapshot.data(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }
```

Even for the realtime listener, it reads the last message instead reading what's after it...

```
  StreamSubscription messagesLive({
    Chat chat,
    onEmpty(),
    onAdded(Message m),
    onModified(Message m),
    onRemoved(Message m),
    onFailure(e),
  }) =>
      Services().crud.readLive(
            stream: (chat.messages.isEmpty
                    ? APIs()
                        .chats
                        .collection
                        .doc(chat.chatID)
                        .collection(Constants.messages)
                        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: false)
                    : APIs()
                        .chats
                        .collection
                        .doc(chat.chatID)
                        .collection(Constants.messages)
                        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: false)
                        .startAfter([chat.recentMessage.createdAt]))
                .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
            onEmpty: () => onEmpty(),
            onAdded: (m) => onAdded(Message.model(
              ds: m,
              id: m.id,
              map: m.data(),
            )),
            onModified: (m) => onModified(Message.model(
              ds: m,
              id: m.id,
              map: m.data(),
            )),
            onRemoved: (m) => onRemoved(Message.model(
              ds: m,
              id: m.id,
              map: m.data(),
            )),
            onFailure: (e) => onFailure(e),
          );
```

In the following logs, F is the last message is already visible so it shouldn't be rereading it like the Android logs.

Logs for Android:

```
I/flutter ( 7676): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:263:13)
I/flutter ( 7676): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 7676): │  Getting Missing Messages...
I/flutter ( 7676): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:268:15)
I/flutter ( 7676): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 7676): │  LENGTH
I/flutter ( 7676): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:269:15)
I/flutter ( 7676): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 7676): │  0
I/flutter ( 7676): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:270:15)
I/flutter ( 7676): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 7676): │  Messages: []
I/flutter ( 7676): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:284:13)
I/flutter ( 7676): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 7676): │  Getting Missing Messages Complete.
I/flutter ( 7676): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
I/flutter ( 7676): │ #1   _ChatPageState._initMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:199:11)
I/flutter ( 7676): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 7676): │  Init Live Messages...
I/flutter ( 7676): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Logs for iOS:

```
flutter: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
flutter: │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:263:13)
flutter: ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
flutter: │  Getting Missing Messages...
flutter: └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
flutter: │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:268:15)
flutter: ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
flutter: │  LENGTH
flutter: └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
flutter: │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:269:15)
flutter: ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
flutter: │  1
flutter: └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
flutter: │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:270:15)
flutter: ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
flutter: │  Messages: [F]
flutter: └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
flutter: │ #1   _ChatPageState._missingMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:284:13)
flutter: ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
flutter: │  Getting Missing Messages Complete.
flutter: └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
flutter: │ #1   _ChatPageState._initMessages (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:199:11)
flutter: ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
flutter: │  Init Live Messages...
flutter: └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
flutter: │ #0   Funcs.log (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:136:35)
flutter: │ #1   _ChatPageState._initMessages.<anonymous closure> (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/home/sections/chats/chat_page.dart:205:19)
flutter: ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
flutter: │  Message: F
flutter: └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Assuming `[chat.messages.last.createdAt]` is a timestamp, maybe this is being caused by the way a timestamp is interpreted in both systems, try logging it both in ios and android and checking if there are any differences between it's value.

Comment: I am dealing with a similar issue, and Rafael's theory seems very plausible. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `createdAt`'s type is Timestamp(Firestore type).

I had same issue. My problem was the type. The type I passed to `startAfter()` was `DateTime`(Dart's type). But the type of the field in my `Firestore` was Timestamp(`Firestore`'s type).

So I converted the type of the data into Timestamp before I pass to `startAfter()` and it worked!